# Determine whether an infinite straight line (one direction) from a point intersects with a line segment in 2D

Tags: c++, geometry, 2d, line, intersection

I'm trying to find an algorithm that is optimized for finding whether an intersection exists between a (infinite) line and a line segment.

Here on SO and other sites I've seen many line segment - line segment intersections and line - line intersection algorithms, yet finding a 'simpler?' version for one infinite line (from a point in one direction) and a line segment is very hard.

I currently have something like (line segment - line segment intersection):

```
bool lineSegmentsIntersect(float pX, float pY, float p2X, float p2Y, float qX, float qY, float q2X, float q2Y)
{
    // p and p2 define the first line segment
    Point2D p(pX, pY);
    Point2D p2(p2X, p2Y);

    // q and q2 define the second line segment
    Point2D q(qX, qY);
    Point2D q2(q2X, q2Y);

    Point2D r = p2 - p;
    Point2D s = q2 - q;

    float uNumerator = (q-p)*r;
    float denominator = r*s;

    if (uNumerator == 0 && denominator == 0) {
        // co-linear, so do they overlap?
        return ((q.x - p.x < 0) != (q.x - p2.x < 0) != (q2.x - p.x < 0) != (q2.x - p2.x < 0)) ||
            ((q.y - p.y < 0) != (q.y - p2.y < 0) != (q2.y - p.y < 0) != (q2.y - p2.y < 0));
    }

    if (denominator == 0) {
        // lines are parallel
        return false;
    }

    float u = uNumerator / denominator;
    float t = ((q-p)*s) / denominator;

    return (t >= 0) && (t <= 1) && (u >= 0) && (u <= 1);

}
```

Where the * operator is defined as:

```
float Point2D::operator*(const Point2D &rhs)
{
    return x*rhs.y - y*rhs.x;
}
```

Though I'm looking for something simpler/faster. I'm trying to check whether a point is within a closed shape (the shape is defined by some points and (linear interpolation) straight lines between them.)

From the point I shoot a ray in a predefined direction.

Preferrably [1, 0] or [0, 1] (this could be used as a constant given) if that makes the math easier which I think it might.

Then I check if the ray intersects with each line segments and if that is an odd number it is inside the shape.

Some things I'm thinking of:

If we decide to always shoot a ray straight up then if both of the points of the line segment are below the point we already know that it doesn't intersect.

Comment: Is this the problem you are trying to solve: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: Line-in-one-direction is called a **ray**. You may have better luck searching for that.

Comment: @AdamBurry yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

See Hormann and Agathos, "[The point in polygon problem for arbitrary polygons](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.19.5578&rep=rep1&type=pdf)", Computational Geometry 20 (2001) 131–144. for an efficient implementation of the winding algorithm.